# Prisma - Unique constraint failed, while there is no unique field in schema

Tags: mysql, typescript, prisma

I am using prisma with three models,

```
model User {
  id               String            @id @default(cuid())
  name             String            @unique @db.VarChar(35)
  email            String            @unique @db.VarChar(512)
  password         String            @db.VarChar(1024)
  details          String            @default("") @db.VarChar(512)
  avatar           String            @default("/default-avatar.svg") @db.VarChar(150)
  activity         String            @default("Online") @db.VarChar(25)
  likes            Int               @default(0)
  suggestions      Boolean           @default(false)
  verified         Boolean           @default(false)
  blockedUsers     BlockedUser[]
  comments         Comment[]
  communities      Community[]
  communityMembers CommunityMember[]
  followers        Follower[]
  friends          Friend[]
  messages         Message[]
  posts            Post[]
  openDMs          DM[]
  interests        UserInterest[]

  @@map("user")
}
```

```
model Community {
  id          String              @id @default(cuid())
  title       String              @unique @db.VarChar(35)
  details     String              @db.VarChar(512)
  memberID    String?
  membersUser User[]
  members     CommunityMember[]
  interests   CommunityInterest[]
  posts       Post[]

  @@map("community")
}
```

```
model CommunityMember {
  id          String    @id @default(cuid())
  nickname    String?
  userID      String
  communityID String
  user        User      @relation(fields: [userID], references: [id])
  community   Community @relation(fields: [communityID], references: [id])
  owner       Boolean

  @@map("community_member")
}
```

I have a route in my backend that causes the problem. It creates a new community member table with prisma client and connects the existing user and community to itself, with their ids.
When I do this, I get an error: `Unique constraint failed on the constraint: community_member_communityID_key`

Here is the code with the creation of the community member:

```
await prisma.communityMember.create({
  data: {
    nickname: response.account.name,
    user: {
      connect: { id: response.account.id }
    },
    community: {
      connect: { id: communityID }
    },
    owner: false
  }
});
```

I have tried dropping the database and resetting the prisma migrations, with no luck.
When I view the table in mysql, it is apparent that the `communityID` and `userID` fields are set as unique, so I think this problem has to do with prisma migrate.
Does anybody know what's happening, and how I can successfully create these fields without them being unique?

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using connect? According to documentation
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes
In nested writes you should use create:

```
await prisma.communityMember.create({
    data: {
      nickname: response.account.name,
      user: {
        create: [
            {id: response.account.id}
        ]
      },
      community: {
        create: [
            {id: communityID}
        ]
      },
      owner: false
    }
})
```

Comment: Because the user was already created, I just want to connect the community member to the user